# How to convert the Mathematica matrix to MATLAB format and using MATLAB to verify the solution?

Tags: matrix, export, matlab

I have got the solution of the matrix system and get the solution using `LinearSolve`, and now I want to use MATLAB to see whether it can generate the same solution, **so now the question is how to convert the Mathematica matrix to MATLAB or save as .mat files?**

```
AA={{0.681598, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.681598, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0.82559, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -0.82559, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.21126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.681598, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.681598, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.46714, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -1.46714, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {24459.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.44599*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -52649.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.26499*10^7, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 14813.6,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -1.48136*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -21733.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.17336*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  14813.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.48136*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -21733.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.17336*10^7, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 24459.9, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -2.44599*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -52649.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.26499*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1.83821, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.83821, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.737568, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.35581, 0, 0, 0,
   0, -1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.737568, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.737568, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.35581, 0,
   0, 0, 0, -1.35581, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.544007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.83821, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.83821, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, -1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, -6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.32342*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  2.43273*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.95223*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  6.59663*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0.527102, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.902105, -0.0381047, 
  1.97961*10^-18, 0.032252, -0.0134366, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89717, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.11357, 
  0.05251, -1.1669*10^-18, -0.0448925, 0.0203351, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.726018, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.0986374, -0.829503, 2.94472*10^-17, -0.0104496, -0.0199249, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.37738, 0, 0, 0, 
  0.131642, -1.21095, -3.50757*10^-17, 0.0193318, 0.0226718, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, -0.0349483, 
  0.0685689, -1., 0.0685689, -0.0349483, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 
  0.0487879, -0.0819742, -1., -0.0819742, 0.0487879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.726018, 
  0, -0.0199249, -0.0104496, 1.28285*10^-17, -0.829503, -0.0986374, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.37738, 0, 
  0.0226718, 0.0193318, -1.44857*10^-17, -1.21095, 0.131642, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0.527102, -0.0134366, 0.032252, 
  3.3025*10^-18, -0.0381047, -0.902105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89717, 
  0.0203351, -0.0448925, -4.28565*10^-18, 0.05251, -1.11357, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89157*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -4.80815*10^6, 3.94552*10^6, 5.01417*10^-10, -651517., -421070., 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.80819*10^7, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 7.14445*10^6, -6.39465*10^6, -7.75403*10^-10, 1.62243*10^6, 
  272901., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1.3027*10^7, 0, 0, 0, 3.94552*10^6, -5.17264*10^6, -6.08506*10^-10, 
  2.81443*10^6, -651517., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, -2.47143*10^7, 0, 0, 0, -6.39465*10^6, 8.32061*10^6, 
  9.22064*10^-10, -4.91195*10^6, 1.62243*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  7.68341*10^-9, -5.12227*10^-9, 1.23481*10^-10, 2.79397*10^-9, 
  1.10012*10^-8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, -9.77889*10^-9, 
  7.91624*10^-9, -1.23481*10^-10, -3.95812*10^-9, -1.28639*10^-8, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.3027*10^7, 
  0, -651517., 2.81443*10^6, -2.42715*10^-10, -5.17264*10^6, 
  3.94552*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -2.47143*10^7, 0, 1.62243*10^6, -4.91195*10^6, 1.46968*10^-10, 
  8.32061*10^6, -6.39465*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.89157*10^7, -421070., -651517., 
  4.57265*10^-10, 3.94552*10^6, -4.80815*10^6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.80819*10^7, 272901., 
  1.62243*10^6, -4.80592*10^-10, -6.39465*10^6, 7.14445*10^6, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.886273, 
  0.043591, -2.39217*10^-18, -0.0368646, 0.0152343, -0.781879, 
  0.0567719, 1.78127*10^-17, -0.0244502, -0.0138963, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.13544, -0.0635594, 1.26461*10^-18, 
  0.0543889, -0.0248018, -1.30933, -0.0962959, 4.51115*10^-18, 
  0.0442529, 0.0433231}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0.113137, 0.803033, -3.41274*10^-17, 0.0116013, 0.0231257, 
  0.209736, -0.783976, 3.06846*10^-17, -0.00228765, -0.0664327, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.158865, 1.25301, 
  4.19225*10^-17, -0.0239344, -0.026909, -0.354315, -1.30513, \
-1.92218*10^-17, 0.0238072, 0.123574}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0398838, -0.0794265, 1., -0.0794265, 
  0.0398838, -0.0204021, 0.174613, -1., 0.174613, -0.0204021, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0590519, 0.0979871, 1., 
  0.0979871, -0.0590519, -0.014461, -0.222673, -1., -0.222673, \
-0.014461}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0231257, 
  0.0116013, -1.49261*10^-17, 0.803033, 
  0.113137, -0.0664327, -0.00228765, -9.15279*10^-17, -0.783976, 
  0.209736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.026909, -0.0239344, 1.72177*10^-17, 1.25301, -0.158865, 
  0.123574, 0.0238072, -2.22052*10^-17, -1.30513, -0.354315}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0.0152343, -0.0368646, -3.79996*10^-18, 0.043591, 
  0.886273, -0.0138963, -0.0244502, 1.00555*10^-16, 
  0.0567719, -0.781879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -0.0248018, 0.0543889, 5.16276*10^-18, -0.0635594, 1.13544, 
  0.0433231, 0.0442529, -1.71668*10^-17, -0.0962959, -1.30933}, {0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  4.64675*10^6, -3.78095*10^6, -4.82725*10^-10, 592772., 
  424926., -340251., 160852., -5.49545*10^-11, -129052., 204067., 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -7.403*10^6, 6.67194*10^6,
   8.06008*10^-10, -1.74152*10^6, -247425., 431093., -180426., 
  1.6481*10^-11, 145890., -229877.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, -3.78095*10^6, 4.96241*10^6, 
  5.87177*10^-10, -2.67944*10^6, 592772., 160852., -101539., 
  6.36591*10^-11, 72933.6, -129052., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 6.67194*10^6, -8.67901*10^6, -9.57219*10^-10, 
  5.15799*10^6, -1.74152*10^6, -180426., 
  126839., -3.86899*10^-11, -83747.7, 145890.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6.98492*10^-9, 
  4.19095*10^-9, -1.23481*10^-10, -3.20142*10^-9, -1.11759*10^-8, \
-4.83124*10^-9, 2.2701*10^-9, -6.14733*10^-11, -3.95812*10^-9, 
  2.09548*10^-9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  9.77889*10^-9, -6.51926*10^-9, 1.23481*10^-10, 4.19095*10^-9, 
  1.29221*10^-8, 4.88944*10^-9, -2.96859*10^-9, 6.14733*10^-11, 
  6.98492*10^-9, 1.16415*10^-9}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 592772., -2.67944*10^6, 2.48436*10^-10, 
  4.96241*10^6, -3.78095*10^6, -129052., 72933.6, 
  5.17967*10^-11, -101539., 160852., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, -1.74152*10^6, 
  5.15799*10^6, -1.35105*10^-10, -8.67901*10^6, 6.67194*10^6, 
  145890., -83747.7, -8.18553*10^-11, 126839., -180426.}, {0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 424926., 
  592772., -4.54748*10^-10, -3.78095*10^6, 4.64675*10^6, 
  204067., -129052., -3.20825*10^-11, 160852., -340251., 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -247425., -1.74152*10^6, 
  4.81898*10^-10, 6.67194*10^6, -7.403*10^6, -229877., 145890., 
  9.28378*10^-11, -180426., 431093.}, {1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1., 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1., 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 27.725 I,
   0. - 4.06836 I, 0. - 3.0604*10^-16 I, 0. + 1.71575 I, 
  0. + 0.558657 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0. + 81.0898 I, 0. + 12.2025 I, 0. - 4.88115*10^-16 I, 
  0. - 5.87267 I, 0. - 6.85412 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 7.52439 I, 0. + 13.9334 I, 
  0. - 1.01465*10^-15 I, 0. - 0.13776 I, 0. + 2.30907 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 22.3807 I, 
  0. + 40.2481 I, 0. + 9.40814*10^-16 I, 0. - 2.19887 I, 
  0. - 8.34859 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 2.30907 I, 0. + 0.13776 I, 
  0. - 1.73896*10^-15 I, 0. - 13.9334 I, 0. + 7.52439 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 8.34859 I, 
  0. + 2.19887 I, 0. - 1.37134*10^-15 I, 0. - 40.2481 I, 
  0. - 22.3807 I}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0. - 0.558657 I, 0. - 1.71575 I, 0. + 4.38062*10^-15 I, 
  0. + 4.06836 I, 0. - 27.725 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. + 6.85412 I, 0. + 5.87267 I, 
  0. - 1.95554*10^-15 I, 0. - 12.2025 I, 0. - 81.0898 I}};


bb={0., 0.807353 + 0.127872 I, 0., 
 0.807353 - 0.127872 I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.807353 - 
  0.127872 I, 0., -0.807353 + 
  0.127872 I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., \
0., 0., -0.00173224 - 0.026907 I, -0.0382822 - 0.0843441 I, 
 4.76335*10^-18 - 5.75795*10^-17 I, -0.0382822 + 
  0.0843441 I, -0.00173224 + 
  0.026907 I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.21339 + 
  0.0781167 I, -1.90178 + 0.863183 I, 0., -1.90178 - 
  0.863183 I, -1.21339 - 0.0781167 I};
```

But if using

```
<< ToMatlab.m
ToMatlab[AA]
```

We get:

```
[0.681598E0,0,0,0,0,(-0.681598E0),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ...
\

  0,0,0,0.146714E1,0,0,0,0,(-0.146714E1),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ...
\
```

Which is really not what we want.

By the way, will the accuracy lose when converting the matrix?
**And maybe MATLAB will not give the same solution as Mathematica.**

Now I want to use MATLAB to see whether it can generate the same solution, so how to convert the Mathematica matrix to MATLAB or save as .mat files?

Comment: Can Matlab read a CSV? Export in a format both can handle

Comment: No need for ``"ToMatlab`"`` Just do `Export["filename.mat",AA]`.

Comment: "By the way, will the accuracy lose when converting the matrix? " Yes an no. Matlab stores everything in double precision floating point number, so does the mat format. When Mathematica exports to .mat it converts all numbers to doubles (if possible). In particular it converts exact integers to doubles. But since some of the matrix entries are already doubles, no actual precision will be lost.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, well received and thank you very much!

Comment: I would instead bring the MATLAB matrix to Mathematica using [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) and then use [ExpressionLineDiff](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExpressionLineDiff/) to compare both.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to use

```
Export["filename.mat",AA]
```

But after that, we have to use

```
AA=load("AA.mat").Expression1
```

rather than

```
AA=load("AA.mat")
```

to load the matrix into MATLAB.

Comment: You can export the matrix under a different name with `Export["AA.mat", "x" -> AA]`. Also, it is enough to do `load("AA.mat")` and the variable from the file will be added to MATLAB's workspace.